# Join data from two tables with autoincrement id from two databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, t-sql

I would like to join data from tables from two databases. One is filed with predefined values (itemId, itemName) and other is filled by user (itemId, itemName, userId). Atributes itemId and itemName are the same, from first table we select all data, from second we select data by userId and combine these two results.

Joined data should be distinguish because ids are autoincrement and could be the same(doubled). We would like to fill drop down list with this data for example with datasource and dictionary (int is itemId, string is itemName)  we could only have valueFiled and valueText in dropDownList but ids of these two tables could be the same and lather we don`t know from wich table is item selected by id.

Is there any elegant way to joint this, maybe with temp tables that we always when user is logged in join these two tables in temp table etc...

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Could you give a set of simple example data, say 4 rows from each table, and then the result you are looking for from your query.  It initially sounds like you want a pretty simple join - but clarity would help.

Comment: And in addition to Nt's question, are you asking about MySQL or SQL Server (or both)? And which version(s)? That might affect the answer.

Comment: Are there duplicates in each individual table or across the two tables?

Comment: table1(id, name -> 1 apple, 2 banana, 3 orange) table2(id, name, username -> 1 mango, 2 pineapple, 3 strawberry) in drop down I wanna set datasource like dictionary<int, string> so I can get selected item by id from tables here is the problem because apple and mango have the same id, and if I select from database by 1 there are 2 items with this id. But I can`t set flag in ddl for table1/table2. I use mssql and sql server 2008, and there are no duplicates in tables, names are unique

Comment: Maybe I can add to id 0 for table1 and 1 for table2 because when I set datasource to dropDownList he create id(string) name(string) as value/text so I could append this two numbers(as my type) and lather I could now by this last number in wich table this item is and I won`t have duplicated ids in dropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a union. Use a literal value to identify the source.

```
select 'predefined' as source, itemid, itemname
  from predefined_values_table
union all
select 'user', itemid, itemname
  from user_supplied_values_table
  where userid = ?;
```

If you can accommodate only two columns, you might be able to use something like this instead. But you'll have to undo the string concatenation to get the id number.

```
select 'p:' || itemid, itemname
  from predefined_values_table
union all
select 'u:' || itemid, itemname
  from user_supplied_values_table
  where userid = ?;
```

Comment: This is not the best solution for me because union all join two tables and duplicates ids, lather if I select something by id and have two ids 1, how can I know wich is from table1 and wich from table2 ... I can`t set the flag in ddl, because it could only have text/value field so if I set dictionary like datasource this sets id and name

Comment: You know which table it comes from by examining the "source" column.